# SQL query and joins

Tags: sql, join

Please see my query below:

```
select I.OID_CUSTOMER_DIM, I.segment  as PISTACHIO_SEGMENT,
   MAX(CASE WHEN S.SUBSCRIPTION_TYPE = '5' THEN 'Y' ELSE  'N' END ) PB_SUBS,
   max(case when S.SUBSCRIPTION_TYPE ='12' then 'Y' else 'N' end) DAILY_TASTE,
   MAX(CASE WHEN S.SUBSCRIPTION_TYPE ='8' THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END) COOKING_FOR_TWO
FROM WITH_MAIL_ID i   JOIN CUSTOMER_SUBSCRIPTION_FCT S
ON I.IDENTITY_ID = S.IDENTITY_ID 
WHERE S.SITE_CODE ='PB'and S.SUBSCRIPTION_END_DATE is  null
group by I.oid_customer_dim, I.segment
```

In this one I am getting 654105 rows, which is lower than the one of the joins table `with_mail_id` which has 706795 rows.

Now, for the qc purpose my manager is wondering as why I am not having all the rows in my final table. I tried to remove all the filters but the results are still not same in both tables. What am I doing wrong?

I am not very good in SQL yet and this thing is really confusing me.

Comment: You have a JOIN with condition, two WHERE conditions and then you GROUP BY ... and you *still* wonder that the number of rows in the result differs from the number of rows in the first table? Seriously?

Answer (score 2):

You're doing an [inner join](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29#Inner_join) on the two tables, so only rows from WITH_MAIL_ID that can join against CUSTOMER_SUBSCRIPTION_FCT will be returned. Additionally you have a group clause.

First the join. If you want to return all rows regardless of the join condition, you can use a [left join](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29#Left_outer_join), but in this case all the S. columns will be NULL, and you'll have to deal with that.

If you run this, you might see the count is the difference:

```
select count(*) from WITH_MAIL_ID i
left join CUSTOMER_SUBSCRIPTION_FCT S 
    on I.IDENTITY_ID = S.IDENTITY_ID
where s.IDENTITY_ID is NULL
```

The most likely thing however is that it's just the grouping. If you are grouping on two columns and selecting the max of various other columns based on that grouping, you would expect that the number of rows returned is less than the original table, otherwise why bother grouping?

If I have data like this:

```
groupkey1  value
1          2
1          10
2          1
2          1
```

Then I group by groupkey1, and select MAX(value) I would get 2 rows `[1,2], [2,1]`, not 4 rows.